# Salesforce API: Create relationship of multiple Person Accounts to one Case

Tags: c#, soap, salesforce

I working on an integration with one of our customers that requires using the Salesforce SOAP API.

The project involves borrower information for loans.

The customer wants a Person Account created for a borrower and one for a co-borrower. They want to then have the borrower and co-borrower Person Account objects to be associated to the same Case object.

I'm new to the Salesforce API but as far as I can tell there is no way to link many accounts to one case even if those Accounts are Person Accounts.

Is it possible to do what I want? Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to deal with this.

- If there will be only one co-borrower, you could just create a lookup field on Case object to link to Account/Contact Object.
- If you will have multiple co-borrowers, and you only want to see a related list with Contacts and probably the relationship/role like "Co-Borrower" you could use [Case Contact Role](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contactroles.htm&language=en)
- If you have multiple co-borrowers and want to see some field values from each of their Account/Contact, please create a Junction Object like "CaseAccount" to init many-to-many relationship between Case and Account/Contact.

Comment: There will never be more than one co-borrower. After posting my question I discovered the Case Contact Role. I will take a look at lookup fields and Junction Objects. If I don't use Case Contact Role I think a lookup field might meet the needs of the client.Thanks.